# How to make passwords "match" while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, password

In the installation of wubi, or Ubuntu 12.04.3  it asks for a password, but won't accept any I choose. It says they don't match. Match with what?  I don't use a password on my laptop so how can I match a password I haven't got?

Answer (score 2):

When you install Ubuntu (no matter *how* you install it), you enter a password for the first user account, created during installation.

You are asked **to enter the password twice.** You have to put in exactly the same password both times. Otherwise, you would think Ubuntu was using the password you had in mind, but it would be using some mistype of it!

So, your password has to match what you typed **the first time you entered it.**